# Flutter / Dart : List of maps vs List of Widgets? Which is better?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, widget, maps

I am creating a sort of "interactive dictionary". The dictionary will be composed of WORDS (as entries), obviously. So I defined what a 'word' is : a series of elements : a main English word, a list of synonyms, a list of antonyms, a translation in French etc...

So far, I have created a "WORD WIDGET" which contains all these fields.
My wordBank List will therefore contain a "List of Word Widgets".

I was wondering if it is a good way to organize the data, of if a list of MAPS would be better ?
Will there be a difference in performance when using the list, sorting, getting elements etc... ?

This is the way I structured it :

````
enum Nature {
  nom_masc,
  nom_fem,
  adjectif,
  adverbe,
  verbe,
  verbe_irr,
  preposition,
}

class Word {
  final int id;
  final Nature nature;
  final String theme;
  final List<String> french; // the first element is the primary word
  final List<String> english; // the first element is the primary word
  final String image;
  final String sound; // to be used as label2 in case of input type question
  final String wDef; // a written definion of the main word
  final String oDef; // an oral definition of the main word
  final String phon; // a phonetic transcription of the word

  Word({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.nature,
    @required this.theme,
    @required this.french,
    @required this.english,
    this.image,
    this.sound,
    this.wDef,
    this.oDef,
    this.phon,
  });
}
```
````

Answer (score 4):

Always prefer a list of core data instead of a list of UI widgets. There are a lot of advantages :

1. It always a good practice to keep your backend and frontend decoupled.
2. Keeping a List of Maps will help you to re-use the data in that list anywhere in your app. Like say you want to make another list of the same data but the widget design will be different or maybe you only want to display some of the data in the map, these conditions can be easily satisfied by a list of Map than a list of widgets.
3. Compare the data types of each. An object of Map type will take less space as it only contains the data. But on the other hand, an object of a Widget will take up a lot of space depending on the depth and child widgets of widget tree.
4. If you keep a list of Maps, it will be easy to customize your resultant list view. Say while displaying the ListView you want to give a different color to the child widget based on the some other data present on the same page. It will be a lot easier and simpler to execute using a List of Map.

There are many more advantages plus it keeps the code clean and easy to manage.

Comment: This is the way I structured it so far :

Comment: I put code in the question now to make it clearer.

Comment: Above one is fine as it's only containing the data used to create a Widget and not the widget itself. Using maps instead of that will just increase the complexity with negligible performance increase.

Comment: so you think creating a class "WORD" is a decent idea ? I can continue that way ? My wordBank is a list of "WORD".

Comment: Yes go for it. And say in future you need to pass this data to a REST API or something and you need to convert it into a Map or JSON String, just override the toMap and toString methods of the Word class to do that.

Comment: "override the toMap and toString methods of the Word class to do that" : this sounds interesting... but as an awful beginner... I don't really understand ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood from your description, there are few things worth mentioning:

1. Don't have a list of widgets rather have any data structure to store the data (List, Map anything depends on the use case) and wrap it into a widget while displaying them to the user.
2. Now to store this data based on your use case, using a map can be beneficial as it can reduce the search time when you are querying any word you want as in the dictionary, there is only a unique word with a particular spelling. A list is suitable for storing any data when you don't have any special condition (like dictionary here) on the data stored in it, so a linear search is performed every time you search for an element.

So you can have a map of words (String) to word object and based on the word you want, you can query that map, retrieve the data and wrap that data into the WordWidget while displaying it to the user.

Also, as a general practice in software development, we try to keep things as loosely decoupled as possible. So, a layer (or data structure) that provides data should only serve this purpose and a layer that takes data and wraps it into a UI element should be separate. This way your code will be maintainable and extendible too based on any future use case.